# After dynamically adding TextBox and Label, then the DropDownList control's SelectedIndexChanged event is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I have three `DropdownList` named

1. drpUniversity
2. drpFaculty
3. drpSupervisor

in my page. 
In `drpUniversity` has a list of University and in last index has Others if the listed Universities are not sufficient for users.

Like as:

1. American University,
2. George Washington University,
3. Florida Hospital College of Health Sciences
4. and Others

Now, in the `drpUniversity_SelectedIndexChange` event I have add a `Label` and a `TextBox` when the user select the Others (or last index).

**My Code:**

```
 protected void drpUniversity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (drpUniversity.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() == "Others".ToString())
            {
                int rowcount = mytable.Rows.Count;
                HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
                row.ID = "tbl_row" + (rowcount + 1);
                HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
                cell1.ID = "tbl_cell1" + (rowcount + 1);
                HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();
                cell2.ID = "tbl_cell2" + (rowcount + 1);
                cell1.Attributes["class"] = "contact";
                cell2.Attributes["class"] = "contact";
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = "tbQty" + (rowcount + 1);
                tb.Width = 276;
                Label lblotherUniver = new Label();
                lblotherUniver.ID = "lbluniversity";
                lblotherUniver.Text = "University Name";
                cell2.Controls.Add(lblotherUniver);
                cell1.Controls.Add(tb);
                row.Cells.Add(cell2);
                row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                mytable.Rows.Insert(8, row);
                mytable.DataBind();
            }
        }
  }
```

**But, the problem is when its creating a `TextBox` and a `Lable` then the other `DropDownList` named drpFaculty's and drpSupervisor's `SelectedIndexChange` events are not working.

 In my drpSupervisor SelectedIndexChange event have This Code:**

```
protected void drpSupervisor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtSupervisorEmail.Text = drpSupervisor.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
     txtSupervisorEmail.Visible = true;
}
```

*This is not working after Select Others from drpUniversity.
 Otherwise this is working.
 Please help me to solve this problem.*

Comment: Why do use if (IsPostBack) in event that suppose to happen on postback?
And please put some asp.net code.

Comment: Now, I am not using `if(IsPostBack)`. Though its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a javascript error in your code. Please check javascript error console in broswer.

Comment: I am not using javascript here.

Comment: I mean asp.net generated javascript which can cause this issue. probably update panel can be reason for this issue.